# Arcmap 10.1 Export Map Module Missing Save Button and Name Field

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, export

I'm trying to export a map to jpg and have lost the save buttons and name field in the module. The module points to the correct folder, but I've lost scroll bars and fields. Anyone have any ideas how to fix?  Copy map to clipboard works except for the loss of one layer.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to post a picture of your Save Map dialog? I'll +1 your question in case you need more reputation to do so.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough points to post it. The folder just shows existing jpgs that I was able to save earlier. No other options to name jpg or save.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I've added the screen capture.  I've deleted my normal template as recommended on an ESRI forum, tried opening other maps, and still have the outcome.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have service pack 1 installed?

Comment: Aha, I did at one time, but had to reinstall last November and thought that it would load by default. I have product version 10.1.0.3035, but Administrator says ArcGIS Service Pack: 0. Weird. I'll install SP1 and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Update. SP1 didn't work. So I'm thinking of reinstalling again.

Comment: This issue may be Windows version specific. I did not ever try ArcGIS for Desktop 10.0 with Windows 7, but if you are using the latter it may make an upgrade to 10.1 or preferably 10.2 a wise thing to consider.

Comment: Hi, Editing the registry worked. I changed the value of the "ShowOptionsPanel" under the "ExportDlg" folder from zero to one and restarted ArcMap. Worked like a charm.

Comment: thanks a lot......i have the same problem, and now solved by following the above steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer from the ESRI Forum as others were having the same problem. 
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/42377-Export-map-no-options-for-details-filename

Editing the registry worked and I can see my options now.

1. Close ArcMap and go to the Start menu.
2. Type in regedit in the box to bring up Registry Editor
3. Back up your registry first.
4. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\Desktop10.0\Export
5. Expand ExportDlg folder, in right panel, double click on "ShowOptionsPanel"
6. Enter "1" for Value Data and OK.
7. Close Registry and restart ArcMap. Test Export feature which should now show options.

Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be encountering the same issue as someone who reported it via the **[ArcGIS Discussion Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/42377-Export-map-no-options-for-details-filename..)**.

A piece of advice from there from Kyle Gallagher which could work is:

> Open the Export Map window and put your cursor in the File Name
>   section. Hit the Tab key 4 times to activate the Options button that
>   is hidden (should be right after Cancel), press space bar once to
>   expand the Option section.

Comment: I have the same problem and the above doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, edit the registry key for the ExportDlg folder, change the ShowOptionsPanel to 1 and it should reappear. The Tab key workaround did not work for me. Thanks for the heads up.